# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null - How to solve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

I get the error *"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null."* when trying to get data from an API and then display it onto the web application.

I have a feeling there is an issue with either 'view and model' or the product class, but I'm not sure how to fix it as I feel like I have tried a lot of stuff.
Hope anyone can help - thanks in advance

I have included some of my code below:

Product.cs:

```
  public class Offer
    {
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public double discount { get; set; }
        public string ean { get; set; }
        public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastUpdate { get; set; }
        public double newPrice { get; set; }
        public double originalPrice { get; set; }
        public double percentDiscount { get; set; }
        public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
        public int stock { get; set; }
        public string stockUnit { get; set; }
    
}

    public class Product
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string ean { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clearance
    {
        public Offer offer { get; set; }
        public Product product { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public object extra { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string zip { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hour
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public DateTime open { get; set; }
        public DateTime close { get; set; }
        public bool closed { get; set; }
        public List<double> customerFlow { get; set; }
    }

    public class Store
    {
        public Address address { get; set; }
        public string brand { get; set; }
        public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
        public List<Hour> hours { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

public class Root
{
    public List<Clearance> clearances { get; set; }
    public List<Store> store { get; set; }

}
```

Homecontroller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    private async Task<Root> GetProducts()
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("API Client");

        var result = await client.GetAsync("/?zip=9000"); 

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(content);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = await GetProducts();
        // Pass the data into the View
        return View(model);
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

Index:

```
        @{ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";}
@{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}

@model Madspild.Models.Root;
<div class="text-left">

    @foreach (var item in Model.clearances)
    {
        <div>
            <div> Offer: @item.offer</div>
            <div> Product Description: @item.product.description</div>

        </div>
    }

</div>
```

Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddHealthChecks();

        services.AddHttpClient("API Client", client =>
        {
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.sallinggroup.com/v1/food-waste/"); /

             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "token");
              client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        })
       
        .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] {
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        }));
    }

   
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
           app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the named http client doesn' work properly in net core you have to replace

```
services.AddHttpClient("API Client", client =>
        {
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.sallinggroup.com/v1/food-waste/"); /

             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "token");
              client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        })
```

with

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

your action

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
//manually configure all urls and headers
```

You still can use typed httpclient but it is more reliable to do this by good old way.